# Approximation of probability Borel measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

If $M $ is a metric space, is it true that every Borel probability measure on $M $ can be approximated by measures with finite support  (they are concentrated on a finite number of atoms)?

I tried to prove this,that's not hard to 
Check it is true for Euclidian spaces, but how about the general case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since in the tags you mention ergodic theory, a good pointer is Sigmund's result saying that in hyperbolic dynamics (he proved the result in more generality) the weak closure of the measures on (finite) period orbits is the set of all invariant measures.